# MirrorLink 1.0 and 1.1 comparability

Tags: android, mirrorlink

I have started researching the MirrorLink area as I am experiencing issues with establishing a connection between my infotainment system (Toyota touch 2) that run with MirrorLink version 1.0 and my server (Samsung Galaxy S7) that works with version 1.1. when the two unites are connected the MirrorLink connection is detected by the server but nothing is displayed on the infotainment system.

My questions:

1. Does a server running version 1.1 can support a client running version 1.0?
2. How can I debug the connectivity between the two units?
3. If the answer for point 1 is NO then what are the options for a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the MirrorLink specification: ETSI has adopted and published MirrorLink 1.3 version. Look for ETSI TS 103 544 specification. It comes in 29 parts. MirrorLink 1.3 is an extension of MirrorLink 1.0/1.1/1.2. You will find references in the specification, on how the other versions work. Older versions are not publicly available.

https://www.etsi.org/standards-search#&search=103544

Regarding registration on Car Connectivity Consortium website: You can always register as a developer. This is for free. It gives you information on how to develop on Android. You can also download the free MirrorLink Client head-unit emulator. It runs on Linux.

Comment: [13. Core Architecture](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103500_103599/10354413/01.03.00_60/ts_10354413v010300p.pdf#page=16) specifically mentions "mismatched" versions having to be supported nonetheless. So, the answer to OP's question seems yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the Galaxy S7 and the Toyota Touch 2. I bought a Toyota Avensis and want to display the navigation on the screen.

1.) As i know, the Mirrorlink Server is provided by the Operating System, and i read in several forums topics from "ROM"-Modifiers, that they tried Mirrorlink 1.1 prevent to start running everytime you connect your Samsung Device to the USB cable. According to some slides I found by the Car Connectivity Consortium the server (the phone) has implemented the "MirrorLink Common API" in his body.

[image: Mirrorlink Common API]

The next question would be, can you emulate a Mirrorlink 1.0 phone with the "Mirrorlink Common API"? I only found s.th. about a Fake Common API, that is not making the phone to be a mirror link server (and only works on phones without mirrorlink):

[image: Common Fake API]

Toyota explains it, that they do not Support 3rd Party Application, what Mirrorlink 1.1 is providing additionally. As i know, the Toyota Touch 2 with Go supports some Internet Functionalities with an own app store. I guess Toyota don't want you to use third Party applications and buy the Navigation System instead.

I got an old Galaxy S3, which runs with Android 4.3 and when i download the DriveLink App i can get DriveLink to the Screen. Here is my Report (sorry it is on my blog):

http://www.capri-soft.de/blog/?p=2550

3.) My dream is to implement a Raspberry Pi Project - i want raspberry to provide a mirrorlink 1.0 server and connect to the head Unit. But i did not find any specifications of the Mirrorlink protocol on the web. On the Website of the car connectivity consortium there is a "Forum" area, but if you want to join it, you have to Register with a Company email adress of one of the implementing manufactures (i.e. Toyota, Volkswagen, Samsung....) and i am not working for those companies.

I read that the Screen mirroring itself is working with VNC - if someone knows how to provide a VNC Server over USB please tell me :-)...

Comment: The main thing which I am trying to understand is whether the mirror link versions are backward compatible? If 1.1 server supports 1.0 client then Toyota might have block this in some way and I will be able to  further debug this from the software perspective , if this is not supported then I am wasting my time.
Running android on Raspberry pi should not be an issue as far as I know, it is just a matter of building an app with Mirror link API.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 ... I found Verso 2017 model and Touch 2 (without GO) with working mirrorlink 1.1...

I'm from Slovenia, EU.. I have S7 edge with android 8 with usual system upgrades.

Install Samsung Car Mode 7.0.S30.5261778 (Android 8.0+) By Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/car-mode-for-galaxy/car-mode-for-galaxy-7-0-s30-5261778-release/car-mode-for-galaxy-7-0-s30-5261778-android-apk-download/

Then Instal Sygic Car connected Navigation (free Premium demo for 7 days)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sygic.incar&hl=en

When I connect the USB cable it automatically connects (enable Mirrorlink support on the mobile) to Touch 2. Press Phone&Online button (right middle) on the Touch 2 and you should get displayed additional Car Mode option. Click on it and if you have parking brake ON you will get Car mode app showing. Note this is not full mobile screen miroring but showing the Car mode app only. Inside the app you can select Sygic car navigation. When the sygic is running and you release the parking break, the navigation window stays visible on the screen. Licensing is not cheap however the proof of concept is working. The Toyota navigation costs hundreds of euros, Sygic is far less.

Comment: Hi Bozo, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to be much more precise here. Your answer does not address the OPs questions.